# QXmlStreamReader says that i'm at the end of an XML file while in the middle of it

Tags: c++, xml, qt

Hello the problem is that i'm reading a XML file using QXmlStreamReader to read in Appointments for my Calendar but when I'm switching from `AppointmentSolo` to `AppointmentRepeat` atEnd() returns true for some reason.

This is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AppointmentSolo>
    <Length>1</Length>
    <AppointmentSolo0>
        <Date>10 09 2011</Date>
        <Begin>15:11</Begin>
        <End>23:12</End>
        <Title>Final test</Title>
        <Description>Final countdown</Description>
        <hasNotify>1</hasNotify>
        <notify>17</notify>
    </AppointmentSolo0>
</AppointmentSolo>
<AppointmentRepeat>
    <Length>1</Length>
    <AppointmentRepeat0>
        <Date>08 01 2014</Date>
        <Begin>20:08</Begin>
        <End>23:09</End>
        <Type>MONTHLY</Type>
        <Exceptions>
            <Length>1</Length>
            <Exception0>08 09 2014</Exception0>
        </Exceptions>
        <Title>Repeat test</Title>
        <Description>FooBar</Description>
        <hasNotify>0</hasNotify>
        <notify>0</notify>
    </AppointmentRepeat0>
</AppointmentRepeat>
```

And here is the part of my code which reads it and where the problem occurs.

```
if(Rxml.isEndElement() && Rxml.name() == "AppointmentSolo")
{
    qDebug() << Rxml.atEnd() << Rxml.name() << Rxml.hasError();
    Rxml.readNext();
    qDebug() << Rxml.atEnd() << Rxml.name() << Rxml.hasError();
    qDebug() << Rxml.error();
    while(!Rxml.atEnd() && !Rxml.isStartElement())//om aan begin tag te zijn
    {
        Rxml.readNext();
        qDebug() << Rxml.atEnd() << Rxml.name() << Rxml.hasError();
    }
}
```

This is what is outputted

```
false "AppointmentSolo" false
true "AppointmentRepeat" true
3
```

It seems this is a QXmlStreamReader::NotWellFormedError
The parser internally raised an error due to the read XML not being well-formed.
But why is my XML not well formed then?

EDIT: it seems there happens an error (i added the "<< Rxml.hasError()")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML can have only [one root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), so your XML is invalid.

Comment: You mean that i have to place my <AppointmentSolo> and <AppointmentRepeat> in let's say a <Item> ?